# how to cal tfidf in different way

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf

I have two type document, one is labeled, and other is not. 
I want use the labeled document to calculate tf, and use other unlabeled document to calculate idf.

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split(',') for line in open('data/unannotated.csv',encoding='utf-8'))
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=5, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000, keep_tokens=None)
```

This unannotated is unlabeled data, one line is one document.
Based on this data, I got a dict:

```
{'get': 353867,
 'http': 351618,
 'u': 324711,
 'one': 291526,
 'go': 279237,
 'know': 265001,
 'good': 249368,
 'say': 236003,
 'like': 225619,
 'qatar': 223010,
 'time': 191195,
 'would': 188766,
 'think': 187128,
 'people': 182873,
 'make': 180120,
 'need': 166287,
 'take': 157106,
...
}
```

I use next piece of code to calculate tfidf, and it gives all same answer:0.9999999999999946

```
def TFCalculator(question, word):
    if word not in question:
        return 0
    count = dict(Counter(question))
    q_len = len(question)
    return float(count[word]) / float(q_len)

def n_containing(unannotated, word):
    return float(unannotated.get(word,0))

def IDFCalculator(unannotated, word):
    return math.log(float(len(unannotated.keys())) / (1.0 + n_containing(unannotated, word)))

def tfidf(stem, unannotated):
    tfidfVector_ques = range(len(unannotated))
    for word in stem:
        tf= TFCalculator(stem,word)
        idf = IDFCalculator(unannotated, word)
        tfidf = tf * idf
        try:
            tfidfVector_ques[list(unannotated).index(word)] = tfidf
        except:
            pass
    return sparse.csr_matrix(tfidfVector_ques)

def cosine_similarities(question,comment,unannotated):
    X_tfidf = tfidf(question,unannotated)
    Y_tfidf = tfidf(comment,unannotated)
    similarities = cosine_similarity(X_tfidf,Y_tfidf)
    return similarities
```